# Laravel Cache. Increment or Put if value does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Is is possible to replace this line of code with something out of the box.

```
Cache::has('test') ? \Cache::increment('test') : \Cache::put('test', 1, 60);
```

So basically, I need to check if *test* exists in the cache. If yes then increment the value, if not create cache record and set value 1.

Comment: your code looks good and having short hand of if/else. then why do you want to replace with something?

Comment: @rubab-hossain I think maybe something already exists in Laravel. Like that  Cache::incrementOrPut('test', 2, 60);   If test exists, then increment it, if not, put value 2 for 60 minutes.